# Ubuntu server ssh after reboot: Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: server, ssh

I have a server setup where I can ssh to from my mac. The setup is made with a trusted key and it works perfect. But whenever I reboot the server and I that try to login using `ssh my_user@ip` then it says: `Permission denied (publickey).` However if I physically go to the server and log in as my_user, then suddenly I can get remote access by ssh from my mac as well. What do I need to change in my setup?

Comment: Are you using an encrypted home directory by chance?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that I did so when installing yes...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, the problem is that the key is stored in ~/.ssh/authorized_keys

With an encrypted home, you can not log in with the key as your home directory is encrytped.

Move authorized keys to somewhere else, I personally use /etc/ssh/.authorized_keys

You then edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` , add/edit the line

```
AuthorizedKeysFile /etc/ssh/.authorized_keys
```

Restart ssh server.

See also:

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man5/sshd_config.5.html

Comment: I disagree that a single file should be used, this is why `man sshd_config` describes placeholders such as `%u` for the `AuthorizedKeysFile` option.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys

Comment: @0xC0000022L - It is less then ideal, but, %u is not going to work with encrypted home directories. You may list multiple files if you wish, see the man page.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen: You mean SSH can't deduce the username from the connection attempt? I realize that `%h` won't work, but I think I even got it to work with `%u` on a Ubuntu Desktop install, although this was 10.04 or so.

Comment: %u should work, do as you wish ;)