# SSH Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: server, permissions, ssh

I am trying to connect to a Linode (running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS) from my local machine (also running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS)

I have created a private and public key on my local machine and copied my public key to my Linode's authorized_keys file.  However, whenever I try to ssh to my Linode I get the error message `Permission denied (publickey)`.

It's not a problem with how ssh is set up on my Linode because I can ssh to it from my Windows machine using key authentication.

In my `.ssh` directory on my local Ubuntu machine, I have my `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub` files.  Do I need to create an authorized_keys file on my local machine?

EDIT:  This is what I get when I run `ssh -vvv -i id_rsa [youruser]@[yourLinode]`:

```
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Comment: 1) What do the logs on the SSH server say about the time you have this error on the client? (`/var/log/auth.log`) 2) How did you transfer the public key to the server? Always use `ssh-copy-id` to be sure about permissions. Your home directory, the `.ssh` directory and the `authorized_keys` file have strict permission requirements. (see manpage of `sshd` (8) on `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`). 3) Did you generate a new keypair on Ubuntu? In case you reused the key from Windows - you'll have to convert it to OpenSSH format first.

Comment: The command **should** have been `ssh -vvv -i .ssh/id_rsa ....` (note the path to id_rsa!) - please replace - the old log only shows that "we" had no pubKey to send.

Comment: @guntbert I missed out the .ssh because I was already in the .ssh directory.  I also tried it with .ssh/id_rsa but I got the same result

Comment: I see, so I misread - Please answer the questions from @gertvdijk.

Comment: Very useful tutorial: [www.digitalocean.com: How To Set Up SSH Keys](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys-2).

Comment: I had same problem. I could log on as root but not as new_user.  If you can access your server as root or a sudo user you can watch the ssh auth log via "tail -f  /var/log/auth.log". in my case the problem was the new_user was configured with an invalid shell.  "user new_user not allowed because shell /bin/ is not executable".

Comment: (not enough reputation to post as an answer) More recently, this can also happen due to the SHA-1 signature in RSA keys becoming deprecated. Running `ssh -vvv` will report "no mutual signature algorithm" if this is the case. To fix, either update your ssh server to support `rsa-sha2`, or regen your key with `ssh-keygen -t ed25519`, or pass `-o PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes=+ssh-rsa` to the ssh client.

Comment: I had this today with a new user account I had added - the keys were fine and all were installed correctly.  On checking the /var/log/auth.log, I could see that the connection was being refused becasue the user account was not in the AllowUsers list in the server's

Comment: meant to say the server's SSH config file (/etc/ssh/sshd_config).  It is good practice to lock down SSH in this way so only those user accounts that abolsutely need to SSH in, can do.

Answer (score 166):

#### PubKeyAuthentication

**Set up your client**

1. Generate your key.

   ```
   ssh-keygen
   ```
2. Configure ssh to use the key.

   ```
   vim ~/.ssh/config
   ```

   Your config file should have something similar to the following:

   ```
   Host SERVERNAME
   Hostname ip-or-domain-of-server
   User USERNAME
   PubKeyAuthentication yes
   IdentityFile ./path/to/key
   ```

   You can add `IdentitiesOnly yes` to ensure `ssh` uses the specified `IdentityFile` and no other keyfiles during authentication. Setting `IdentitiesOnly` prevents failed authentications from occurring, when `ssh` would otherwise attempt to login with multiple keys.  Setting this is also considered more secure, as you're not leaking information about other keys you have installed, and maintaining separation of your keys between different levels of access.
3. Copy your key to your server.

   ```
   ssh-copy-id -i /path/to/key.pub SERVERNAME`
   ```

   For example, `ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_res.pub -p 22 user@1.1.1.1`

**Troubleshooting**

1. use "-vvv" option
2. Make sure the server has your PUBLIC key (.pub).
3. Make sure your IdentiyFile points to your PRIVATE key.
4. Make sure your `.ssh` directory has 700 and the files within are 600 permissions.

   - `ssh-keygen` will create files and directories for you with the proper permissions
5. `tail -f /var/log/auth.log` (on the server) and monitor errors when you attempt to login
6. If you have many key files, try `IdentitiesOnly yes` to limit the authentication to use the single, specified key.

Comment: FYI, I created a small script at https://github.com/centic9/generate-and-send-ssh-key which runs the necessary steps in one go and additionally ensures all the file/directory permissions which always caused me headaches...

Comment: Just to elaborate step 2: the `IdentityFile` line in ~/.ssh/config must point to the PRIVATE key.

Comment: [Indeed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/34783/10805).

Comment: I wonder why you'd want to set files to have execute permission in step 4?

Comment: It's also very important right permissions per user (use chown and chmod) otherwise you will get an authentication denied even if you server has your public key.

Comment: Why does every question like this contain an answer that tells you to start by generating the key using `ssh-keygen`? OP already said he has a public and private key.

Comment: Posterity and completeness is why.

Comment: While the directory requires 700 permissions, the files do not, they should be 600.

Comment: `tail -f /var/log/auth.log` gave the required info for me

Comment: `authorized_keys` needs `644` I think.

Comment: 600 on `authorized_keys` is the default and all you need under most circumstances.

Answer (score 144):

Sometimes the issue comes from permissions and ownership. For instance, if you want to log in as root, `/root`, `.ssh` and `authorized_keys` must belong to root. Otherwise, sshd won't be able to read them and therefore won't be able to tell if the user is authorized to log in.

In your home directory:

```sh
chown -R your_user:your_user .ssh
```

As for rights, go with 700 for `.ssh` and 600 for `authorized_keys`

```sh
chmod 700 .ssh
chmod 600 .ssh/authorized_keys
```

Comment: This answer helped me. I had taken the advice from [this post](http://askubuntu.com/questions/254776/ubuntu-server-ssh-after-reboot-permission-denied-publickey) and moved my `authorized_keys` file outside of my encrypted home directory. In doing so, I had inadvertently changed ownership to `root:root`.

Comment: Wish I could upvote twice, once for the folder and once for the file. Very important that permissions are exact.

Comment: I changed the permission of my home folder /home/user to 777 by mistake, this make ssh failed. `chmod 777 /home/user` will fix it.

Answer (score 51):

The problem I had was it was using the wrong keys on the client. I had renamed id_rsa and id_rsa.pub to something else.
You can either rename them back to their default, or when you issue the ssh command, use it like this

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/private_key username@host
```

Comment: no, use the public key

Comment: @St3an you put the public key on the server, but when you connected like Todd is here above, you use your private key

Comment: @NathanFiscaletti you must never expose your private key, that's why it's private. The private key is used by your local ssh agent to check that you really give a public key that correspond to your private one. SSH agents between machines can then guarantee that users are who they pretend to be  :-)

Comment: Exactly. Which is why when you connect, you provide your private key to the ssh-client. The server stores your public key. The command in the post above is exactly how private keys are supposed to be used.

Comment: This works like a charm, and finally solved my first connection to the server.

Answer (score 21):

You don't need `authorized_keys` on your client.

You must tell the ssh-client to actually use the key you generated. There are several ways to do that. Just for testing type `ssh -vvv -i .ssh/id_rsa [youruser]@[yourLinode]`. You will have to provide your passphrase every time you want to connect to the server.

If that worked you can add the key to the `ssh-agent` with `ssh-add .ssh/id_rsa` (you will have to provide the passphrase only once for this and it should work as long as you don't logout/reboot)

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have edited my answer to show what happens when I type what you suggested.

Comment: to transfer a key, on the client, use ssh-copy-id

Comment: @bodhi.zazen Thanks, but I have already transferred the key, that isn't the problems

Comment: "You must tell the ssh-client to actually use the key you generated." No, by default it will look for the key in the default path, e.g. `~/.ssh/id_rsa`. Also, the use of a key agent is completely optional and unrelated to the issue as far as I can see.

Comment: @gertvdijk, you are making assumptions here which are not backed by facts yet - we don't know what happened on the system.

Comment: If SSH doesn't automaticly, then there are things done to the system which are not reported. So it should OK to assume default behaviour. But the -vvv are great way of know what the client SSH does. I would like the user to transfer the keys again, with ssh-copy-id. I would goes the problem is on the server side.

Comment: How to pass a passphrase in the same command

Comment: It is possible that ssh-agent will not see a new key in ~/.ssh/id_rsa if it is already using a different key. You'll need to use ssh-add again. Using that as a default for ssh is ignored I think if there are any keys in ssh-agent.

Answer (score 19):

Also check value of `PasswordAuthentication` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and if it's `no` change it to `yes`. Don't forget to restart ssh service after that.

Comment: The OP is not trying to use password authentication. They have some sense and are using public/private key.

Comment: This solved my issue, in some cloud server, after enable ssh login, password login is disabled automatically ...

Comment: The OP didn't have this issue, but others who have a similar issue (e.g. yours truly) may be directed to this question by Google. I am trying to set up a test server within my firewall with password authentication. One might say that's never advisable, but I would like to know that I have the option.

Answer (score 7):

I ran into this issue recently with my web server.

I typically keep a list of authorized keys on all my servers in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys2`.  From my experience, `sshd` will look for `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` or `~/.ssh/authorized_keys2` by default.

In the case of my webserver, the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` had this line

```
AuthorizedKeysFile    %h/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

instead of

```
AuthorizedKeysFile    %h/.ssh/authorized_keys2
```

I applied the latter, restarted my ssh daemon, and solved my problem logging in with ssh using my pubkey.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this helped me figuring out that this line was completely commented out of the config!

Answer (score 7):

Also make sure that the user's home directory (on the server) actually belongs to the user ssh'ing into (was set to root:root in my case).

Should have been:

```
sudo chown username:username /home/username;
```

Comment: I am able to ssh with public/private keys with a user on my local linux box (e.g. abc), different from the user on the remote server (e.g. def@123.456.789). I just had to make sure the local user owned the local .ssh files (e.g. abc:abc, not root:abc)`

Answer (score 7):

Another possible cause could be with the `AllowedUsers` configuration in `/etc/ssh/sshd_conf`.  NOTE: the list is *space* delimited (not comma delimited) as I learned the hard way.

```
AllowUsers user1 user2 user3
```

Answer (score 6):

The following method might work if you can access machineA and machineB independently (e.g. from machineC).

If ssh-copy-id is not working, password authentication could be disabled. **The following is a workaround**.

Having machineA's public key in machineB's authorized keys (i.e. ~/.ssh/authorized_keys) will allow you to ssh from machineA. This also applies to scp.

After generating the key pairs using: `ssh-keygen`

On **machineA**, execute `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`

Sample output:

> `ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaSGMFZW7yB anask@mahineA`

Copy the printed key (<kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, or <kbd>CRTL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>) then add it to the ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file on **machineB**.

For example, execute the following on **machineB**:

> `echo 'ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaSGMFZW7yB anask@mahineA'  >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`

Comment: This one worked for me- it turned out the simplest

Answer (score 4):

Works on Ubuntu 16.04 as well.

The issue is within `sshd_config` file

Here is the ULTIMATE solution:

Log as as a root to you Ubuntu server

```
vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Now go to very bottom and change the value from "no" to "yes".

It should look like this:

Change to no to disable tunnelled clear text passwords

```
PasswordAuthentication yes
service sshd reload
```

to take effect.

Now you can simply a key using following command from your LOCAL machine (aka laptop etc)

So in order to open a new terminal window and NOT log into server, simply use this command:

ssh-copy-id john@serverIPAddress

(Replace john with your username).

you should be good to go

Answer (score 3):

I my case, the client is ubuntu 14.04lts, the server was win 2012 server running cygwin.  I was using 'ssh administrator@x.x.x.x', when the 2012 server directory in cygwin was /home/Administrator.  So it was case sensitive, when I tried 'ssh Administrator@x.x.x.x' (note the capital A on Administrator) then it worked fine.

An error message like 'user not found' would have led me to the solution a lot quicker than 'Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive)'.

Comment: Someone should log an issue with the ssh project suggesting that. I ran into a similar issue.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue when copying a regular user's (e.g. johndoe) public key from a cPanel Centos system over to an Ubuntu server on AWS. As suggested by [gertvdijk](https://askubuntu.com/questions/311558/ssh-permission-denied-publickey#comment393256_311558) above, I checked `/var/log/auth.log` and sure enough it said `Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for directory /home/johndoe`. Turns out I had wrongly 777'ed `/home/johndoe` when trying to set `/home/johndoe/public_html` as the default virtualhost Document Root for apache2 (that's not needed for that task either).

See also the answers [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37164/ssh-and-home-directory-permissions) and [here](http://www.daveperrett.com/articles/2010/09/14/ssh-authentication-refused/)

The server only needs to have the public key in `.ssh/authorized_keys` and the client (computer you're working on) needs to have the private key (.pem, or if using SFTP with Filezilla, .ppk)

Comment: Instead of 777, what should it be?

Answer (score 2):

This is what worked for me, the fix is not mine but I would rather write it down here in case someone else has the same problem.

The original author posted it here: [digital-ocean-public-access-key-denied](http://webdesignforidiots.net/2016/02/digital-ocean-public-key-access-denied-on-existing-droplet/)

```
sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Replace this

```
UsePAM yes
IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
PasswordAuthentication no
```

With this

```
UsePAM no
IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
PasswordAuthentication yes
```

Save the file and restart ssh

```
reload ssh
```

ssh should work now asking for a password

Comment: I wouldn't do that...

Comment: PasswordAuthentication should remain no

Answer (score 2):

Some people wondering may have set up ssh access to be key only on the root account then created a new user and not realised they need to

`ssh root@your-ip-address`

`rsync --archive --chown=[user]:[user] ~/.ssh /home/[user]`

`logout`

Then try again. Replace [user] with your new user account.

This is common when setting up a new server on DigitalOcean when you've used ssh-keys on setup.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/initial-server-setup-with-ubuntu-18-04

Answer (score 2):

Owner permission for the `~/.ssh` directory, should contain your username.

```sh
chown -R $USER:$USER /home/$USER/.ssh
```

***Note**: Make sure `$USER` is your correct `username` (not `root`).*

Answer (score 1):

If all else failed, check that your login user belongs to the ssh's AllowedGroup. That is, your users is a member of the group shown at the following line in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` on the server:

```
AllowGroups ssh #Here only users of 'ssh' group can login
```

Answer (score 1):

For those Putty users like me who came to this thread, you may also get this error if you forgot to add user user@Ip !

Others being permission on key file chmod to 600)

```
ssh 1.1.1.1 -i /path/to/.pem file 
Permission denied (publickey).`

ssh user@1.1.1.1 -i /path/to/.pem file
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as described in the question. The output from executing `ssh -vvv -i id_rsa [youruser]@[yourLinode]` on the client machine was similar to that described in the question. I checked all the file and directory permissions as advised in the other answers, and they were correct.

It turned out that when copying the generated file `id_rsa.pub` to the server machine, as file `~username/.ssh/authorized_keys`, **I'd accidentally omitted the word `ssh-rsa` from the start.** Adding it solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had added a **wrong key** to the server. Because I did not use the command with an option to specify a certain key it added the standard key-file.

Make sure you did use `ssh-copy-id -i CORRECT_KEY.pub`

This wrong key worked great with one client, because this client also had this key. But when trying to connect with another client to the same server it obviously failed.

Also, which might be interesting is that you get more logging with `ssh -vv` instead of just the single `-v`.

Answer (score 1):

Another causes for this error are:

1. Incorrect user in `ssh -i id_rsa [user]@[yourLinode]`
2. Outdated SSH RSA key. OpenSSH v8 deprecated RSA algorithm by default.
   Regenerate your keys with: ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -f ~/.ssh/your.key -C "My key"

This might be the case especially if you're getting the possible debug warning:

```
debug1: send_pubkey_test: no mutual signature algorithm
```

Here is the good article that describes possible issues for this error: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-linux-fix-permission-denied-errors/

Other references:

1. https://www.ssh.com/academy/ssh/keygen#ssh-keys-and-public-key-authentication
2. https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserverkb/ssh-rsa-key-rejected-with-message-no-mutual-signature-algorithm-1026057701.html

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue was caused by copying over an `.ssh` directory from an older machine. Turns out that my older SSH config was using DSA keys which have since been [deprecated](https://www.openssh.com/legacy.html). Switching to a new pair of keys, this time RSA-based, solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

In general the quickest way to understand the reason of refused SSH connections is to inspect the SSH server log (assuming you can access the log without the tested SSH connection):

```
sudo systemctl status sshd
```

One possible reason is a move of the connecting client to a new subnet (ISP etc.) combined with a very restrictive filter set up in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, that requires not only a specific pre-defined user name, but also a connection from a pre-defined IPs range:

```
$ cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config | grep Users
AllowUsers <user>@1.2.3.4/16
```