# How to access a VirtualBox VM from Mac using telnet or ssh?

Tags: networking, virtualbox, ssh

I am trying to connect from my mac-terminal to a vm installed locally through `telnet`. But the connection is refused and here is the message:

> telnet: connect to address 192.168.56.101: Connection refused
>   telnet: Unable to connect to remote host

I couldn't fix the problem.

I switched to `ssh`. Again, the same problem:

> Permission denied, please try again.

I followed [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/901407/168777) answer with no success. Any help please !

P.S.: The vm is mininet-vm and the OS is Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: @ThomasWard : The first interface is NAT the second is a Host-only adapter

Comment: Try opening a console on the guest and remoting into itself.