# SSH without password only works one time

Tags: 18.04, ssh, configuration, openssh, hadoop

I want to configure SSH to use it without the need of writing the password. I am using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on Windows 10. I need it to run Hadoop 3.1.1 (https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.1.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html#Standalone_Operation) using the pseudo-distributed mode.

I have tried a lot of different solutions but without any result. I obtained that the first time that I used the command ssh localhost I do not need to write the passphrase but when I write again I have to write the passphrase.

I explain the different steps that I have used:

1. I have created a key using ssh-keygen -t rsa
2. I add the public key to  the authorized_keys files: cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
3. I add the key executing: exec ssh-agent bash and ssh-add id_rsa (Years ago, in this point sometimes I had different problems and I used different solutions: https://superuser.com/questions/1147145/what-are-the-differences-between-the-those-ways-of-using-the-ssh-agent)
4. I execute: ssh localhost

At this point all is right, but, when I execute again ssh localhost, then, I have to write the passphrase. These steps worked fine in the Ubuntu of AWS 3 years ago.

I have tried in the point 3 this other method: https://www.ssh.com/ssh/copy-id

All the possible solutions that I found said the same that I have tried in point 3, or I think that. I have tried to change permissions of authorized_keys and .ssh as I found in other solutions too but without success.

Comment: _"... when I execute again ssh localhost ..."_ - Are you doing `ssh localhost` from the previous SSH session? In other words, are you doing `ssh localhost`, logged in successfully, and then in the same terminal without logging out, doing `ssh localhost` again?

Comment: Also, why would you even need to ssh to localhost?

Comment: This is often seen with automation, such as Ansible, and is a reasonable test when first learning `ssh`.  It threw me off too, at first, but we can also assume that the OP, or other readers, will eventually `ssh` into remote hosts.

Comment: Users unaware of `sudo` sometimes implement access via `ssh` keys to be able to switch users.

Comment: @earthmeLon Nice speculation on why OP is doing `ssh localhost`, but I'd prefer to hear the actual reason from them ;)

Comment: Yes, I am doing ssh localhost after the first one. As I said before, I am testing Hadoop in Pseudo-distributed mode. 3 years ago, this method worked fine in Ubuntu on AWS. This is why I need to configure SSH without the passphrase: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.1.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html#Standalone_Operation

Answer (score 3):

You should take a look at [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/311894/13247) which describes configuring `ssh` for your user (editing `~/.ssh/config`) and other details.

The steps are:

1. Generate your `ssh` key.
2. Add the Host to your `~/.ssh/config` file.
3. Add your **Public** (`.pub`) key to the remote user's `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`

   - This is most easily done with `ssh-copy-id` command.
   - `ssh` is **very** particular about the permissions of `~/.ssh/` and the files found within.  `ssh-copy-id` handles everything for you.
4. Try connecting to the Host:

   - `ssh host`
   - `ssh host -vvv # Verbose output for troubleshooting`

Are you trying to use `ssh-agent` because your keys are protected by a password?  I would recommend working on manually connecting without `ssh-agent` and getting that working.  After you have your key working, you can work on solving any of the `ssh-agent`-specific issues.

To troubleshoot, be sure to use `ssh` in a verbose mode, and also monitor (`tail -f`) the remote server's `/var/log/auth.log` file.  On newer systems, you may have to use `journalctl` (`journalctl -u sshd | tail -f`).

---

Once you've gotten the key working in general, you can look into `ssh-agent` documentation, such as [this set of setup instructions](http://rabexc.org/posts/using-ssh-agent).  Typically the steps are as follows:

1. Generate your keys (as you have already done).
2. Install the keys (as you have already done).
3. Start `ssh-agent`

   - `eval ssh-agent`
   - Only once, not each connection or anything.
   - You can have this happen automatically, depending on when and for which user.
4. Add your key to `ssh-agent`:

   - `ssh-add ~/.ssh/private_key`

Be sure to look into other `ssh-agent` configuration options, such as the duration your keys will remain unlocked.

---

Boiling it down a bit, your problem is most likely one of these:

1. You say you added `ssh-agent` starting, and the addition of your `id_rsa` key (in the past), but now that you've generated a new key, that key will also need to be `ssh-add`'d.

   - Check that `ssh-agent` is actually running on your system if you have problems after adding the key.
   - `ps aux | ssh-agent`
2. You're adding the key to your local file, not the remote user's file.

   - Think of it like you're adding a password, so you need to add the password on the system which should accept it.
   - *Your* remote host is localhost, but this assumes you'll want to be able to work on remote hosts in the future.  However, it still needs to be in the correct `$HOME` directory for the correct user.
3. You say it works a single time?  Does it work twice if you try two times in a shorter timeframe, say one minute?  I am trying to understand if your `ssh-agent` is just set up to lock your key in a shorter timeframe than you've tested.
4. When appending to the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file (`>>`), you initially created the file, and this would be with incorrect permissions.

   - Do not do the following without securing access, and making backups to any remote files.
   - If your 'remote host' is localhost, it **very likely has files you want to keep, such as your keys, and should be backed up before removal.**
   - Delete the entire remote `~/.ssh/` directory and use `ssh-copy-id` to properly key your user on the remote host.
   - This would show up on the remote host's `auth.log` and specify that the file permissions are incorrect.
   - If you continue to experience issues after using `ssh-copy-id` to create the directory and files, post the permissions of `~/.ssh` and your generated key files.
5. After you `ssh` into the remote host, you lose `ssh-agent`, unless you have configured `ssh-agent`, and `ssh` via `~/.ssh/config` to `ForwardAgent yes`.  If you wish to forward `ssh-agent`, you'll have to configure it to allow that, and understand the security implications with that decision.  It should also be noted that `ForwardAgent` may be designed to run on different machines, and it may not be possible to get forwarding working locally because of complications with `ssh-agent` already running.

Comment: THX: 2 problems. If I use 'eval ssh-agent' because when I use ssh-add id_rsa the system return me 'Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.' Then, I have to use 'exec ssh-agent bash'.

Comment: The other problem: I said it works in a single time because I execute 'ssh localhost' and then I do not require to introduce the passphrase. If I execute again 'ssh localhost', then, I have to insert the passphrase.

Comment: Hey, glad you're making some progress.  Could you clarify if everything is working now that you ran `exec ssh-agent bash`? The How-To references this command: `eval \`ssh-agent\``.  Notice the backticks.  Either way, we need to make sure `ssh-agent` runs a single time, and stays up.  If I were you, I'd look into having `ssh-agent` start when you login to X, and verify it starts properly after restarting.  Then use `ssh-add` and it should work.  I'll update the Answer when I understand more of what you're doing to fix it :D

Comment: Maybe, I have solved it now. I had to reset Windows 10 to restart Ubuntu. I tried to do 'ssh localhost but it returned me ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused'. I did the same steps than before (I found it in different webpages): purge and install open-ssh server, configure sshd_config (PermitRootLogin no,PasswordAythentication yes,AllowUsers myaccount,UsePrivilegeSeparation no). I did a service ssh --full-restart. After these steps, all worked fine, except the warning: Remote Host Identification has changed. The difference was the reboot of Windows 10.