# Password required for Gitlab clone after setting SSH Key

Tags: permissions, ssh, git, gitlab

I am trying to clone a Gitlab repository inside a cluster computer. It asks me for the password for git@gitlab... And once I enter it, it denies the permission.

I have set an SSH Key in Gitlab inside the cluster (I copy pasted the key in authorized-keys file) but it is not being used by Gitlab (I checked it in Gitlab, it says it was never used).

I am getting the following:

```
[user@eu-login-12-ng ~]$ git clone git@gitlab.ethz.ch:user/test.git
Cloning into 'test'...
git@gitlab.ethz.ch's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
git@gitlab.ethz.ch's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
git@gitlab.ethz.ch's password: Connection reset by 129.132.93.72 port 22
```

If I try clone it in my local computer, it works fine.

What can I do?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSH Permission denied (publickey)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/311558/ssh-permission-denied-publickey)

Comment: @earthmeLon I edited the question

Comment: This usually happens when your SSH key isn't added right to your ssh-agent or isn't being served.  When you saved the SSH key that you generated, what did you save it as?  And how did you generate the key?

Comment: The ssh key is in the authorized_keys file from the cluster (inside .ssh folder that was already there), the file was created already, I just copy pasted the key there and in gitlab @ThomasWard