# Can't SSH to my Ubuntu server after changing the default port number

Tags: ssh

I connected to Ubuntu server from my Mac terminal using `ssh root@555.555.55.55` *(not the real IP address)*, then I got an error `ssh: connect to host 555.555.55.55 port 22: Connection refused`. After that I tried the command  `ssh root@555.555.55.55 -p 55555`, then I got the message `root@555.555.55.55: Permission denied (publickey)`.

Before changing the port number I have installed ufw and I changed the port number using `sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

Now I'm not able to connect to my server. Can anyone help me out.

Comment: "*Permission denied (publickey)*" suggests that you DID connect to port 55555. You were refused entry due to incorrect login. Try again using `ssh -v root@555.555.55.55 -p 55555` for more useful diagnostic output.

Comment: Is the server on the same LAN as the MAC? if not, you likely need to change the port forwarding settings on the server network's router if you want to use a different external port number

Comment: FYI you are not going to be able to login as root on a default Ubuntu system.  That's disabled by default, and since the `root` password is not set you need to use SSH public key authentication to login to `root` by default.  You should SSH in as a non-root sudo-enabled account and then use `sudo` on your sudo-enabled account to execute commands as admin.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SSH Permission denied (publickey)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/311558/ssh-permission-denied-publickey)

Comment: @Dan I think you have to see the IP address as an abstraction in the question.. I understand why the OP doesn't want to show his real public IP and port here.