# Setting AuthorizedKeysFile value causes ssh failure?

Tags: ssh, encryption, reboot

Upon rebooting my ubuntu machine remotely over ssh, I was no longer able to ssh to that machine.  [It was suggested](https://askubuntu.com/questions/254776/ubuntu-server-ssh-after-reboot-permission-denied-publickey) that this was due to my home directory [being encrypted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/146511/how-to-check-if-your-home-folder-and-swap-partition-are-encrypted-using-terminal) with the `authorized_keys` locked inside it.  So I took the same suggestion verbatim and added `AuthorizedKeysFile /etc/ssh/.authorized_keys` to my `sshd_config`.

But then I got `Permission denied (publickey)` on any ssh attempt including `ssh localhost`, with "Failed publickey for myusername from 192.168.1.8 port 63398 ssh2" in the `/var/log/auth.log`.  The only way I found to fix this is to comment out the `AuthorizedKeysFile` setting (and maybe also do `sudo service ssh restart`).  Of course this brings back my original problem with ssh-ing after reboot.

My `/etc/ssh/.authorized_keys` has permissions 600 just like the original `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.  Any ideas what is going wrong?

Comment: Move all the public keys from `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` to `/etc/ssh/.authorized_keys` ..the file is most probably owned by root and `600` means only root has `rw` access, not you..make yourself the owner of the file by `chown user /etc/ssh/.authorized_keys` and the permission bits should be `600`....keep `AuthorizedKeysFile /etc/ssh/.authorized_keys` on `sshd_config`.

Comment: @heemayl That works!  I use chown so rarely I never would have thought of that.  Consider posting your comment as a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have rightly put:

```
AuthorizedKeysFile    /etc/ssh/.authorized_keys
```

in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and also correctly moved all the public keys from `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` to `/etc/ssh/.authorized_keys`.

The problem is that `/etc/ssh/.authorized_keys` is owned by `root` and a permission of `600` on the file means that only `root` can read-write the file, not the user you are login as.

To solve the issue make the user owner of the file, if the user is `foobar` then do:

```
sudo chown foobar /etc/ssh/.authorized_keys
```

and keep everything else as it is.

Comment: Actually I copied (not moved) my keys.  Might this cause other problems later?

Comment: @zkurtz No, it should not..